# Change relative path when used _layouts in MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, relative-path

I have an issue with calling controller action from _layouts page. I show a warning message on _layouts page to display on all pages.

The message has link to a controller action. It works fine when I am in root page like `http://localhost:42344/`,

but I am in any another controllers like `http://localhost:42344/eduction/`, `http://localhost:42344/employment/`,`http://localhost:42344/address/`. Url does not work because it 404 error, path changes so `'/Address/ChangePrimaryBadAddress'` changes.

How to handle in this situation? we always travel from controller url to another controller url. So url path always changes.

### _Layouts.cshtml

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">                    
       @Html.Partial("_alerts")
 </div>
```

### _alerts.cshtml

```
 @model dynamic
<div id="displayMessage">    
</div>
```

### js file

```
var msg = "<div class='alert alert-warning' role='alert' style='margin:0'>  Please update your address.  " +
       "<a  class='linkbutton' href='/Address/ChangePrimaryBadAddress'>Change Address</a>"
       +" </div>";

ShowMessage = function(msg) {
if ($.session.get('showwarning') == 'true') {

    $('#displayMessage').html(msg);
    $('#displayMessage').show();
    } else {
    $('#displayMessage').html('');
    $('#displayMessage').hide();
    }
 }
```

### AddressController.cs

```
 public class AddressController : Controller
    {
           ....
           ....
             public ActionResult ChangePrimaryBadAddress()
             {
             }
  }
```

Comment: Can you please also include your AddressController and ChangePrimaryBadAddress method?

Comment: I think you can use @@Html.Action instead of @Html.Partial. that will allow you to pass actionname and controllername

Comment: You must have something else going on. I tried your scenario (using jQuery to place a link on the page in a partial view that's included in `_Layout.cshtml`, with the link URL being relative to the site root) and it was working fine for me in my own local site. Have you checked your routing config? Is the AddressController in a different area than your other controllers?

Comment: @howcheng , my link is not in partial view. It is javascript file which included in _layout.cshtml file.

Comment: It shouldn't matter if the Javascript to add the link to the page is in the page/view itself or in an external file. Is the URL to the address change page supposed to be `http://localhost:42344/Address/ChangePrimaryBadAddress`?